# Blank build.gradle file

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I imported the Bluetoothgatt sample project but it failed to build showing "Enable Gradle Offline mode"

I check my http proxy was correct.I simply added the https proxy as wellin the radle.properties files and synced.It worked and built fine.
But I found that the build.gradle of the Project is emplty.Is it an issue?build.gradle of App is having the contents and it builds fine.
Why I am having the build.gradle empty for the Project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `build.gradle` file does not need to have any content, it does not even have to exist. If you e. g. have a multi-project build with a root project and two sub-projects and configure the sub-projects from the root project build file, you don't need to have the sub-project build files. Which projects take part in a build is defined in `settings.gradle` and only if you need to make stuff in the `build.gradle` of a project you need the file physically.